# Force unique key in view to avoid merge join

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a query. Basically, there are 3 parts to a transaction that can be repeated. I log all communications, but want to get the "freshest" of the 3 parts. The 3 parts are all linked through a single intermediate table (unfortunately) which is what is slowing this whole thing down (too much normalization?).

There is the center of the "star" "Transactions", then the center spokes (all represened by "TransactionDetails", which refer to the hub using "Transactions" primary key, then the outer spokes (PPGDetails, TicketDetails and CompletionDetails), all of which refer to "TransactionDetails" buy it's primary key.

Each of "PPGDetails", "TicketDetails" and "CompletionDetails" will have exactly one row in "TransactionDetails" that they link to, by primary key. There can be many of each of these pairs of objects per transaction.

So, in order to get the most recent TicketDetails for a transaction, I use this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TicketTransDetails] AS
select *
from TicketDetails tkd
join (select MAX(TicketDetail_ID) as TicketDetail_ID 
    from TicketDetails temp1 
    join TransactionDetails temp2 
    on temp1.TransactionDetail_ID = temp2.TransactionDetail_ID  
    group by temp2.Transaction_ID) qq
on tkd.TicketDetail_ID = qq.TicketDetail_ID
join TransactionDetails td
on tkd.TransactionDetail_ID = td.TransactionDetail_ID
GO
```

The other 2 detail types have similar views.

Then, to get all of the transaction details I want, one row per transaction, I use:

```
select *
from Transactions t
join CompletionTransDetails cpd
on t.Transaction_ID = cpd.Transaction_ID
left outer join TicketTransDetails tkd
on t.Transaction_ID = tkd.Transaction_ID
left outer join PPGTransDetails ppd
on t.Transaction_ID = ppd.Transaction_ID
where cpd.DateAndTime between '2/1/2017' and '3/1/2017'
```

It is by design that I want ONLY transactions that have at least 1 "CompletionDetail", but 0 or more "PPGDetail" or "TicketDetail".

This query returns the correct results, but takes 40 seconds to execute, on decent server hardware, and a "Merge Join (Left Outer Join)" immediately before the "SELECT" returns takes 100% of the execution plan time.

If I take out the join to either PPGTransDetails or TicketTransDetails in the final query, it brings the execution time down to ~20 seconds, so a marked improvement, but still doing a Merge Join over a significant number of records (many extraneous, I assume).

When just a single transaction is selected (via where clause), the query only takes about 4 seconds, and the query, then, has a final step of "Nested Loops" which also takes a large portion of the time (96%). I would like this query to take less than a second.

Since the views don't have a primary key, I assume that is causing the Merge Join to proceed. That said, I am having trouble creating a query that emulates this functionality - much less one that is more efficient.

Can anyone help me recognize what I may be missing?

Thanks!

--mobrien118

Edit: Adding more info -
Here is the effective data model:
[image: Transaction Data Model]

Essentially, for a single transaction, there can be MANY PPGDetails, TicketDetails and CompletionDetails, but each one will have it's own TransactionDetails (they are one-to-one, but not enforced in the model, just in software).

There are currently:

- 1,619,307 "Transactions"
- 3,564518 "TransactionDetails"
- 512,644 "PPGDetails"
- 1,471,826 "TicketDetails"
- 1,580,043 "CompletionDetails"

There are currently no foreign key constraints or indexes set up on these items.

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on the underlying tables?

Answer (score 1):

First a quick remark:

> which also takes a large portion of the time (96%).

This is a bit of a (common) misconception. The 96% there is an estimate on how much resources said 'block' will need. It by no means indicates that 96% of the time inside the query was spent on it. I've had situations where stuff that took over half of the query **time-wise** were attributed virtually no cost.

Additionally, you seem to be assuming that when you query/join to the view that the system will first prepare the data from the view and then later on will use that result to further 'work out the query'. This is not the case, the system will 'expand' the view and do a 'combined' query, taking everything into account.

For us to understand what's going on you'll need to provide us with the query plan (.sqlplan if you use SqlSentry Plan Explorer), it's that or a full explanation on the table layout, indexes, foreign keys, etc... and a bit of explanation on the data (total rows, expected matches between tables, etc...)

PS: even though everybody seems to be touting 'hash joins' as the solution to everything, nested loops and merge joins often are more efficient.

(trying to understand your queries, is this view equivalent to your view?)

[edit: incorrect view removed to avoid confusion]

Second try: (think I have it right this time)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TicketTransDetails] AS
SELECT td.Transaction_ID, tkd.*
  FROM TicketDetails tkd
  JOIN TransactionDetails td
    ON td.TransactionDetail_ID = tkd.TransactionDetail_ID
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(TicketDetail_ID) as max_TicketDetail_ID, temp2.Transaction_ID
          FROM TicketDetails temp1 
          JOIN TransactionDetails temp2 
            ON temp1.TransactionDetail_ID = temp2.TransactionDetail_ID  
         GROUP BY temp2.Transaction_ID) qq
    ON qq.max_TicketDetail_ID = tkd.TicketDetail_ID
   AND qq.TransactionDetail_ID = td.Transaction_ID
```

It might not be any faster when querying the entire table, but it should be when fetching specific records from the Transactions table.

Indexing-wise you probably want a unique index on `TicketDetails` `(TransactionDetail_ID, TicketDetail_ID)`

You'll need similar constructs for the other tables off course.

Thinking it through a bit further I think this would work too:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TicketTransDetails] 
AS
SELECT *
  FROM (
            SELECT td.Transaction_ID, 
                   TicketDetail_ID_rownr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.Transacion_ID ORDER BY tkd.TicketDetail_ID DESC),
                   tkd.*
             FROM TicketDetails tkd
              JOIN TransactionDetails td
                ON td.TransactionDetail_ID = tkd.TransactionDetail_ID
        ) xx
 WHERE TicketDetail_ID_rownr = 1 -- we want the "first one from the end" only
```

It looks quite a bit more readable but I'm not sure it would be faster or not...  you'll have to compare timings and query plans.

Comment: Unfortunately, that query is not equivalent - the key field that I want to group based on is TransactionDetails.Transaction_ID (which is a foreign key to the primary key of the "hub" table "Transactions". I want to find the last (by primary key) "PPGDetail", "TicketDetail" and "CompletionDetail" for each "Transaction", however, unfortunately, the only way to get the "Transaction_ID" is thorough intermediate table "TransactionDetails"...
I'll update the post with more structural details of the db. I figured I would be leaving critical details out- just trying to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks, the picture helps a lot, I'll remove my faulty view for now and have a look later on.

Comment: I was able to improve performance by about 36% by creating a "Unique Key" clustered index on the "TransactionDetail_ID" field in each of the 3 tables "TicketDetails", "PPGDetails" and "CompletionDetails". Still much slower than I was hoping for. I'm confident that if I removed the intermediate table (BIG software changes) I would get this down to seconds... My poor design coming back to haunt me.
I would be interested to hear any other ideas you might have!